# Makefile not invoking rule dependencies

Tags: makefile

So here's my question: Why is the following makefile failing to build the only `.c` file in the directory? I have a fairly simple makefile for building my operating system kernel, and for some reason, it's not building the `.c` files required for the `kernel` rule to build.

The directory only contains a single `.c` file and the following `Makefile`:

```
GCCPARAMS = -m32 -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -nostdinc -nostdlib
GPPPARAMS = -m32 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdinc -nostdlib
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -m32 -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib

C_FILES := $(wildcard *.c)
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
S_FILES := $(wildcard *.s)
OBJ_FILES := $(C_FILES:.c=.o) $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o) $(S_FILES:.s=.o)

all: kernel

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(GCCPARAMS) -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) $< -o $@

kernel: $(C_FILES) $(CPP_FILES) $(A_FILES)
    ld -r $(OBJ_FILES) -o ../kernel.o
```

As you can see, I clearly have $(C_FILES) in the list. However, running `make all` or `make kernel` yields the following output:

```
ld -r core.o   -o ../kernel.o
ld: cannot find core.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'kernel' failed
make: *** [kernel] Error 1
```

Now, I've called even added to the `kernel` rule a print routine to test the `C_FILES` variable which does, in fact, print `core.c` (The one `.c` file in the directory), and the linker clearly received the `OBJ_FILES` list, so why is it not building `core.c`?

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for removing the C tag, it wasn't actually a relevant tag, I forgot to remove it before posting.

Comment: Add $(OBJ_FILES) to the prerequisites of the kernel rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your object files as prerequisite to the kernel rule, because the kernel rule depends on them. It only depends indirectly from the source files.

```
kernel: $(C_FILES) $(CPP_FILES) $(A_FILES) $(OBJ_FILES)
    ld -r $(OBJ_FILES) -o ../kernel.o
```

Comment: Yep, completely missed that. Also, unrelated to the error, I forgot to add $(LDPARAMS) after `ld`, and also typed `A_FILES` instead of `S_FILES`, but it's working!